# Route all internet traffic through Wireguard peer

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, wireguard

I have a Wireguard server S and two clients : A & B. All are on different networks. Only S is reachable. A and B can only connect to S.
I want to route the Internet traffic of B (an optionnaly S) through A.

I tried several things such as :

https://serverfault.com/questions/1074729/route-all-traffic-through-wireguard-peer/1074734#1074734?newreg=7692f5689bcb449883a05c1f72cdd012

[Routing WireGuard peer's traffic via another peer](https://superuser.com/questions/1776851/routing-wireguard-peers-traffic-via-another-peer)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Internet Gateway as a Spoke

We have an endpoint with WireGuard running on it, Endpoint A, from which we want to access the Internet. To get from Endpoint A to the Internet in this scenario, however, WireGuard traffic needs to go through two hops: one through the VPN hub, Host C; and the second through a spoke of the hub, Host β. However, while we want to use Host β as the Internet gateway for Endpoint A, we don’t want that for Host C — Host C itself can use the default routes at Site C to access the Internet as needed.
Hub with an Internet Gateway Spoke

[Details of the network used in this explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAGZG.jpg)

Within our WireGuard network, Endpoint A has an IPv4 address of 10.0.0.1 and an IPv6 address of fd10:0:0:1::1; Host C has an IPv4 address of 10.0.0.3, and an IPv6 address of fd10:0:0:3::1; and Host β has an IPv4 address of 10.0.0.2 and an IPv6 address of fd10:0:0:2::1. Host C has a public IP address of 192.0.2.3, allowing Endpoint A and Host β to each establish a WireGuard tunnel to it.

### Endpoint A

On Endpoint A, when the WireGuard network is up, we want to send all Internet traffic through Host C, so we configure AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 for Host C in Endpoint A’s WireGuard config:

```
# /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf

# local settings for Endpoint A
[Interface]
PrivateKey = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEE=
Address = 10.0.0.1/32, fd10:0:0:1::1/64
ListenPort = 51821

# remote settings for Host C
[Peer]
PublicKey = jUd41n3XYa3yXBzyBvWqlLhYgRef5RiBD7jwo70U+Rw=
Endpoint = 192.0.2.3:51823
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
```

0.0.0.0/0 is the entire IPv4 space, and ::/0 is the entire IPv6 space. (If you don’t care about IPv6 traffic, you can omit the IPv6 addresses and address blocks from this and the other WireGuard configurations.)

### Host C

On Host C, we want to send all the traffic destined for 10.0.0.1 or fd10:0:0:1::/64 to Endpoint A, and all other traffic that comes through our WireGuard network on to Host β. So we configure WireGuard on Host C with AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/32, fd10:0:0:1::/64 for its Endpoint A [Peer] section, and AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 for its Host β [Peer] section.

But since we don’t want all of Host C’s traffic to go to Host β — just traffic forwarded through the WireGuard network — we configure the routes for this WireGuard interface to use a custom routing table, via the interface’s Table = 123 setting. And we use a PreUp command to add a policy routing rule that directs the host to use this table only for traffic coming in from this WireGuard interface (ip rule add iif wg0 table 123 priority 456):

```
# /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf

# local settings for Host C
[Interface]
PrivateKey = CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCGA=
Address = 10.0.0.3/32, fd10:0:0:3::1/64
ListenPort = 51823
Table = 123

# IPv4 forwarding & routing
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
PreUp = ip rule add iif wg0 table 123 priority 456
PostDown = ip rule del iif wg0 table 123 priority 456

# IPv6 forwarding & routing
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
PreUp = ip -6 rule add iif wg0 table 123 priority 456
PostDown = ip -6 rule del iif wg0 table 123 priority 456

# remote settings for Endpoint A
[Peer]
PublicKey = /TOE4TKtAqVsePRVR+5AA43HkAK5DSntkOCO7nYq5xU=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/32, fd10:0:0:1::/64

# remote settings for Host β
[Peer]
PublicKey = fE/wdxzl0klVp/IR8UcaoGUMjqaWi3jAd7KzHKFS6Ds=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
```

### Host B

Similar to the previous Site Gateway as a Spoke scenario, on Host β, we want to send all the traffic destined for the 10.0.0.0/24 and fd10::/56 networks back through Host C — so that’s what we use as the AllowedIPs setting for Host C in Host β’s WireGuard config:

```
# /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf

# local settings for Host β
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBFA=
Address = 10.0.0.2/32, fd10:0:0:2::1/64
ListenPort = 51822

# IPv4 forwarding
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
# IPv4 masquerading
PreUp = iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -j MARK --set-mark 0x30
PreUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o wg0 -m mark --mark 0x30 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -t mangle -D PREROUTING -i wg0 -j MARK --set-mark 0x30
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING ! -o wg0 -m mark --mark 0x30 -j MASQUERADE

# IPv6 forwarding
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
# IPv6 masquerading
PreUp = ip6tables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -j MARK --set-mark 0x30
PreUp = ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o wg0 -m mark --mark 0x30 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = ip6tables -t mangle -D PREROUTING -i wg0 -j MARK --set-mark 0x30
PostDown = ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING ! -o wg0 -m mark --mark 0x30 -j MASQUERADE

# remote settings for Host C
[Peer]
PublicKey = jUd41n3XYa3yXBzyBvWqlLhYgRef5RiBD7jwo70U+Rw=
Endpoint = 192.0.2.3:51823
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.0/24, fd10::/56
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Note that in Host β’s configuration for Host C, we’ve also included a PersistentKeepalive = 25 setting. This ensures that Host β pokes a hole through any NAT (or egress-only) firewalls between Host C and Host β, allowing Endpoint A to initiate connections through the WireGuard network to Host β. You can omit this setting if there are no NAT or egress-only firewalls between Host C and Host β (but if you do that, make sure you instead set up Host C’s WireGuard config to include the public IP address of Host β in its Endpoint setting for Host β).

Also note that we’ve included some iptables rules in Host β’s WireGuard configuration. These iptables rules masquerade packets from the WireGuard network when Host β forwards them out to Site B. You can omit these rules if the LAN router (or each individual endpoint) at Site B is already configured to route traffic destined for the WireGuard network (10.0.0.0/24) back through Host β.

### Test It Out

After starting up our configured WireGuard interfaces on each host (Endpoint A, Host C, and Host β), we can run cURL (or a regular webrowser) from Endpoint A to access Google (or any other Internet site) through our WireGuard network:
``
$ curl google.com

301 Moved
...
```

## Reference :

copy-pasted from https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2022/06/multi-hop-wireguard/#internet-gateway-as-a-spoke (saved me from 2 weeks of unsuccessful search...)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.