# WireGuard: Server on Ubuntu 22.04 and Peer on MacOS - Active but no connection

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireguard

I have a cloud server with Ubuntu 22.04 and wireguard server installed and a MacOS device with the WireGuard app installed. The app shows an active connection but neither is the IP address changed nor do I see an active connection on the server. My configuration files look as this:

```
/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf 
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.1/24, cce7:c18e:3cd5::2/64

ListenPort = 41194
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = ufw route allow in on wg0 out on ens192
PostUp = iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ens192 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = ip6tables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ens192 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ufw route delete allow in on wg0 out on ens192
PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens192 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o ens192 -j MASQUERADE

PrivateKey = <server_private_key>
```

My peer configuration looks like this:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <peer_private_key>
Address = 10.8.0.2/24, cce7:c18e:3cd5::2/64

[Peer]
PublicKey = <server_public_key>
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.0/24, cce7:c18e:3cd5::/64
Endpoint = dunno.com:41194
```

Firewall has open UDP port 41194 and the rules from the wg0 configuration are also in place:

```
41194/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere   
41194/udp (v6)             ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)            
Anywhere on ens192         ALLOW FWD   Anywhere on wg0        
Anywhere (v6) on ens192    ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6) on wg0
```

WireGuard server is running:

```
● wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wg-quick@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (exited) since Sat 2023-12-16 11:22:50 UTC; 8s ago
   Docs: man:wg-quick(8)
         man:wg(8)
         https://www.wireguard.com/
         https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/
         https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8
         https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg.8
Process: 5925 ExecStart=/usr/bin/wg-quick up wg0 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 5925 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    CPU: 239ms

Dec 16 11:22:50 localhost wg-quick[5925]: [#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
Dec 16 11:22:50 localhost wg-quick[5925]: [#] ip -4 address add 10.8.0.1/24 dev wg0
Dec 16 11:22:50 localhost wg-quick[5925]: [#] ip -6 address add cce7:c18e:3cd5::2/64 dev wg0
Dec 16 11:22:50 localhost wg-quick[5925]: [#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
Dec 16 11:22:50 localhost wg-quick[5925]: [#] ufw route allow in on wg0 out on ens192
Dec 16 11:22:50 localhost wg-quick[5956]: Rule added
Dec 16 11:22:50 localhost wg-quick[5956]: Rule added (v6)
Dec 16 11:22:50 localhost wg-quick[5925]: [#] iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ens192 -j MASQUERADE
Dec 16 11:22:50 localhost wg-quick[5925]: [#] ip6tables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o ens192 -j MASQUERADE
Dec 16 11:22:50 localhost systemd[1]: Finished WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0.
```

I can active the peer connection and the app shows a green light but when calling pages like https://whatismyipaddress.com/ I still see my local IP. Also, wg on ther server does not show any active connection:

```
#wg show wg0
interface: wg0
public key: <public_server_key>
private key: (hidden)
listening port: 41194
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

After reading @Michalng's comment (thanks for that!) I understood that the `AllowedIPs` define the URLs that are called on my peer and should be routed through the WG server. So I changed that setting to `::/0, 0.0.0.0.0/0` as suggested and I now see that data is passed through the connection to the server. And, as mentioned, I do get the DNS error. So I added the IP of my openWRT Router to the config of the peer:

```
[Interface]
....
DNS = 192.168.200.1
```

When calling `nslookup google.com` this works fine on my peer's terminal but in the browser I cannot open the same page - it just loads endlessly.

I am using the WireGuard app on MacOS and this says Data sent: X MBbut running wg show all on the server only shows the wg0 interface.

So, a tiny bit seems to be missing. What is it?

Comment: Are you only aiming to access the VPN server system and in case other VPN peers with their plain `10.8.0.0/24` or `cce7:c18e:3cd5::/64` IP addresses? Because nothing else is currently routed through the tunnel with this config. Only requests to addresses defined in `AllowedIPs` are tunnelled. And LAN-side hostnames are only resolved if you define a `DNS` which resolves these as well. If you want all requests to be tunnelled, use `0.0.0.0/0, ::/0`. Also compare with: https://superuser.com/questions/1801791/route-all-internet-traffic-through-wireguard-peer

Comment: Hi @MichaIng, thanks for your comment. I tried that and updated my question accordingly.

Comment: The connection being “up” means nothing, because WireGuard is mostly stateless. Check the output of `wg` (on both ends). Is the expected peer there? Does it show a successful handshake on the peer?

Comment: I am using the WireGuard app on MacOS and this says `Data sent: X MB`but running `wg show all` on the server only shows the `wg0` interface.

Comment: So, just to make extra sure: Your server, on Ubuntu, does not show any peers in the `wg` output, yes? That would mean its configuration is incomplete.

Comment: Yes, @DanielB, the command `wg show all` only lists the wg0 interface but no connections.

Answer (score 2):

Your WireGuard setup is not complete. The Ubuntu host is missing the peer configuration for the macOS host.

To set up WireGuard between two hosts, you need:

- on Host A

  - Host A’s private key
  - Host A’s listen port
  - Host B’s public key
  - Host B’s IP address(es) and/or subnet(s) (“allowed IPs”)
- on Host B

  - Host B’s private key
  - Host B’s listen port
  - Host A’s public key
  - Host A’s IP address(es) and/or subnet(s)

All of these must be exchanged beforehand. To establish an association between the two hosts, at least one of them must be able to reach the other’s UDP listen port. This setup stuff could be considered a pain, that’s why Tailscale exists.

You must add a *peer* entry on your Ubuntu host with the macOS host’s public key. You do not need to add an endpoint though. If all is well, both sides will list the other as a peer. Seeing as you’re using *wg-quick*, it could look like this:

```ini
[Peer]
PublicKey = R6gGtDkUJCfVYXpRrem1TxlLYGzT/PrfZNp5Cp669Ro=
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32, cce7:c18e:3cd5::2/128
```

(The prefix length on *AllowedIPs* must be chosen appropriately: A “road-warrior” peer would typically have */32* (or _/128). This information is used by WireGuard to route traffic to peers. *On* the peer, the interface would still be configured with the “real” prefix length.)

And then, after having successfully exchanged traffic, you will also see something similar to this in `wg`, on the Ubuntu host:

```
peer: R6gGtDkUJCfVYXpRrem1TxlLYGzT/PrfZNp5Cp669Ro=
  endpoint: 203.0.113.54:51820
  allowed ips: 10.8.0.2/32, cce7:c18e:3cd5::2/128
  latest handshake: 38 seconds ago
  transfer: 46.34 MiB received, 995.54 MiB sent
```

---

If the host that is initiating the association (macOS host in your case) is behind NAT, you might want to enable keepalive packets there.

Comment: I though OP did just paste the upper part of the server config, but seems you are right and the peer block is missing. But I suggest you edit your config, remove the `Endpoint` and `PersistentKeepalive` keys, and set `AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32, cce7:c18e:3cd5::2/128`. Because you do not want the server to send all packets to any possible peer to this one peer, and you do not want it to actively connect and keep alive a connection to a peer. On a common server-client model, the client should be the only one which opens and in case keeps connections alive.

Comment: Just a note, OP: I rejected your edit. I purposely chose the wording, because WireGuard does not have servers and clients but only peers.

Comment: Hi @DanielB, thanks for your suggestion. That did the trick. Now I do see the peer on my Ubuntu host. Unfortunately, the pages in the browser load endlessly even with the DNS entry stated in my last edit.

Comment: Does the peer show a successful handshake? If yes, it’s time to whip out `tcpdump` (or whatever packet sniffer you prefer) to analyze what traffic is going where in which state.

Comment: Thanks for adapting most of the edit/suggestion. People are copy&pasting much without understating, so a conservative approach is IMO better. The prefix length is mostly about whether you want to access the host only (`/32`), or its LAN (`/24`), or everything through it (`/0`). The server usually accesses the client host only, while a client usually wants to access more through the server. @AntonSack for LAN access (DNS from router), you need to enable IP forwarding on the Ubuntu host. This can be done via `sysctl` and in case `iptables`. I can paste the commands in some hours when back home.

Comment: Hi @MichaIng, in my original post you see the ip forwarding that I created.

Comment: @AntonSack sorry for the late reply. To enable IP forwarding, you need as well `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` (or adding to `/etc/sysctl.d`) for IPv4 and for IPv6: `net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_ra=2 net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=2 net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1 net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1`. The `accept_ra` thing is required, since with IPvv6 forwarding enabled, by default the system assumes router mode and does not accept RAs (Router Advertisements for SLAAC etc) anymore. This re-enables it.

Comment: And you might need to allow it via `iptables` (or `nftables`) as well: `iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT` and `ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT`